# Angular 4/Material 2: scroll event not firing

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular-material2

I am trying to detect when the window is scrolled in my Angular 4 app, but the events don't seem to be firing, either when attaching the `onscroll` event directly to the `<body>` element, or using something along these lines in my component:

```
this.eventSubscription = Observable.fromEvent( winRef.nativeWindow, "scroll" ).subscribe( e => {
  // do something
} );
```

There are all sorts of posts all over the web, but there doesn't appear to be a definitive answer. One post suggests that encapsulation needs to be set to `Native` on the parent element if the component is within a `<router-outlet>`. I tried this: didn't work, and it ruined my Material components.

My component template looks like this:

```
<!-- home.component.html -->
<div>
    <p *ngFor="let item of playlistItems$ | async">
        {{ item | json }}
    </p>
</div>
```

Component itself:

```
// home.component.ts  
@Component( {
    selector: 'beyond-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ]
} )
export class HomeComponent {

    playlistItems$: Observable<Array<IPlaylistItem>>;
    eventSubscription;

    constructor( private store: Store<fromRoot.IState>, private winRef: WindowRef ) {
        this.store.dispatch( playlist.loadPlaylist() );
        this.playlistItems$ = this.store.select( fromRoot.getPlaylistItems );

        this.eventSubscription = Observable.fromEvent( winRef.nativeWindow, "scroll" ).subscribe( e => {
            // do something
        } );
    }
}
```

Can't for the life of me work out what's going on. Events just aren't firing! I am using Material 2, which might add to the complication. Am I even subscribing to the right event? Is it really `window:scroll`? Do I have the wrong end of the stick?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code all you need is:

```
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    console.log('You scrolled!');
  }
```

Adding this to a component works for me. Note adding to the body may not work as that's not part of your app. I'm also using material and that had no side effects with the above code.

Check out the plunkr here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/no6czB

You need to show the console of course to see the result.

Comment: @serlingpa But where did you try it? if you tried to attach it to the body, then that may not work as it's not part of the angular app. Try and attach it to a component, such as app.component, what do you see. If you see nothing then some other piece of bespoke code is crushing all scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues when trying to load table entries asynchronously. In the end, using a directive to capture the scroll event worked perfectly and it is also reusable. I haven't used on it on the <body> however I am guessing that if you wrap everything in a <div> and apply the directive there it will work fine. This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from 

'@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[rzScrollTracker]'
})
export class ScrollTrackerDirective {
  @Output() updateLoad: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  previousValue = 0;
  scrollDir: string = undefined;

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    const tracker = event.target;
    if(tracker.scrollTop > this.previousValue) {
      this.scrollDir = 'down';
    } else {
      this.scrollDir = 'up';
    }
    // console.log('scrollDir:', this.scrollDir);

    let limit = tracker.scrollHeight - tracker.clientHeight;
    // console.log(event.target.scrollTop, limit);
    if (event.target.scrollTop === limit) {
      // console.log('end reached');
      this.updateLoad.emit(true);
    }
    else if (event.target.scrollTop <= Math.floor(limit / 8) && this.scrollDir === 'up') {
      // console.log('scrolled to top');
      this.updateLoad.emit(false);
    }
    this.previousValue = tracker.scrollTop;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

I am also tracking the direction of the scroll but you don't have to.
You can then use the directive on any other element/component. I have used it successfully on a tbody element and a div:

```
<tbody rzScrollTracker (updateLoad)="updateLoadFactor(nestedFilter, $event)"
      <tr *ngFor="let row of filteredResultsInView[nestedFilter]['values']; let j = index">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" 
            [value]="row.toString()" 
            [disabled]="!areEnabledFromView[nestedFilter]"
            id="checkrads_{{nestedFilter}}_{{i}}_{{j}}" 
            [checked]="selectedResultsObj[nestedFilter][row.toString()]"
            #cbox
            (click)="selectClickedElement(nestedFilter, cbox)">
          <label for="checkrads_{{nestedFilter}}_{{i}}_{{j}}">{{ row.toString() }}</label>
        </div>      
      </tr>
      <tr> &nbsp;</tr>
      <tr *ngIf="resultsInProgress[nestedFilter]">
        Fetching results...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The 'updateLoad' event emitted by the directive is captured in the component and a function is called to modify the displayed data. 
I hope this helps!